# What's the difference between DISTINCT_SCAN and IXSCAN in explain output?

Tags: mongodb, explain, mongodb-3.4, distinct

In Mongo 3.4 `explain("executionStats").distinct(...)`, for some queries 
the winning plan contains an `IXSCAN` step, and for other queries it contains an `DISTINCT_SCAN` step.

What is the difference between the two? Is one of them faster than the other?

Answer (score 3):

They are different stages for different purposes. I believe `DISTINCT_SCAN` is only present when there is an index in the field. An `IXSCAN` stage basically means that the query planner scans an index as one of the stages.

For example:

```
> db.test.createIndex({a:1})
{
  "createdCollectionAutomatically": true,
  "numIndexesBefore": 1,
  "numIndexesAfter": 2,
  "ok": 1
}
```

Doing `find()` on an indexed field will trigger the presence of an `IXSCAN` stage:

```
> db.test.explain().find({a:1})
{
  ...
    "winningPlan": {
      "stage": "FETCH",
      "inputStage": {
        "stage": "IXSCAN",
        "keyPattern": {
          "a": 1
        },
        "indexName": "a_1",
        ...
```

While doing `distinct()` on the indexed field will trigger the `DISTINCT_SCAN` stage:

```
> db.test.explain().distinct('a')
{
  ...
    "winningPlan": {
      "stage": "PROJECTION",
      "transformBy": {
        "_id": 0,
        "a": 1
      },
      "inputStage": {
        "stage": "DISTINCT_SCAN",
        "keyPattern": {
          "a": 1
        },
        "indexName": "a_1",
        ...
```

Note that in both cases, the index `{a: 1}` is used. Without the presence of the index, you will see a `COLLSCAN` stage instead.

One is not "faster" than the other. They're different stages serving different purposes.

Comment: Thanks, however in your example you are getting the `IXSCAN` step on a `find` operation, where it makes no sense to use a `DISTINCT_SCAN`. However in my case both steps are returned from a `distinct` operation.

Answer (score 1):

In short: a MongoDB **DISTINCT_SCAN is a special kind of IXSCAN.**  The difference is that it returns just one document per index key value.  It efficiently skips past duplicates rather than including them all.

For example, let's say you insert the following documents:

- `{a:foo, b:10, c:rat}`
- `{a:bar, b:1, c:cat}`
- `{a:bar, b:2, c:bat}`
- ...
- `{a:bar, b:1000000, c:mat}`

Notice that there are lots of documents with `a=bar`.

If an index is defined as `db.test.createIndex({a:1})` then a DISTINCT_SCAN of that index could be used to return just the following:

- `{a:foo, b:10, c:rat}`
- `{a:bar, b:1, c:cat}` <-- an arbitrary document with the value `a:bar` is chosen from among the many available.  Generally this will be the first one encountered by the index scan.

The original question was "which is faster?"  *All other things being equal*, a DISTINCT_SCAN will be faster *if* there are multiple documents per index value.  However, keep in mind that index scans are configurable with parameters like indexBounds.  So, two IXSCANs using the exact same index can differ significantly in their execution time and the same variability applies to a comparison of DISTINCT_SCAN vs IXSCAN.

In practice I'd give this advice:

- DISTINCT_SCAN and IXSCAN are both good things to see in a query plan.
- Look at the `.explain("executionStats")` to see the details of the index scans' execution.